# ARM Assembly: Need help calculating jump offset for BL opcode

Tags: assembly, arm, offset, machine-code, instruction-encoding

I am working on hacking a game to allow rumble. This requires replacing a line of code in the existing rom with a bl to the new function that I would like to call, however I am having a hard time calculating the necessary offset.

the function I am looking to replace is at address: 0x080011b0

and the location I wish to jump to is at address: 0x0817d7c0

I have also been provided the following example:

```
Calculate the jump address from 0xA20C0 to 0x3E7900. Here it is important to distinguish between arm32bit 
code or thumb16bit code. This game is 16bit.
0x3E7900-0xA20C0=0x345840 
0x345840-4=0x34583C 
High=0x34583C>>12=0x345 
Low=(0x34583C&0xFFF)/2=0xC1E 
machineCode = ((0xFF00 | low) << 16) | (0xF000 | high)= 0xFC1EF345
```

I am fairly certain the game is 16 bit, however I have not been able to even reproduce the results of the example, let alone produce my own jump offset. I believe the values are encoded in little-endian, but I have tried both big and little to no luck (I may be doing something wrong here). Specifically, the calculation starts to break when I perform the bitwise operations (& and |).

If anyone can walk me through the example to produce the offset provided, or can calculate the offset I need and walk me through it I would be very grateful. Bonus points if you can tell me how to do it in 32-bit ARM mode as well.

Comment: What processor are you programming for?  Is this a GBA?  Also: is your own code 16 bit (thumb) code, too?  Can you clobber LR?  Can you perhaps show a memory dump around the site you want to patch?

Comment: Was able to figure it out myself digging through memory in a debugger but I can get a dump if you'd still like.

Edit: Yes, this is to hack a rumble feature of a flashcart into a GBA game.

Comment: You need to divide both halfs. Start with division (shift right 1) and then extact fields.  The masks are wrong when you did it last.

Comment: Game Boy Advance is always little-endian from what I recall

Answer (score -1):

The issue was the algorithm example itself. I used a debugger to see how the jump offset looked in memory and it is nothing like what was provided in example. From there I was able to fiddle with the bits until I got the jump offset necessary. Unfortunately, I still have no idea how I am supposed to calculate it in the first place, but hey, I got the answer.